# Why doesn't multilabel classification give 100% classification on train data (sklearn)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I have the following data:

```
 [
{"Q" : "What nationality is Laplace?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["LOCATION", "DESCRIPTION"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["LOCATION-COUNTRY", "DESCRIPTION-DESCRIPTION"] },
{"Q" : "Who wrote 'Celestial Mechanics'?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["HUMAN"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["HUMAN-IND"]},
{"Q" : "Who created Laplace's equation?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["HUMAN"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["HUMAN-IND"]},
{"Q" : "What operator is named after Laplace?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["ENTITY"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["ENTITY-SYMBOL","ENTITY-WORD","ENTITY-CREATIVE"]},
{"Q" : "Who was one of the first scientists to postulate the existence of black holes?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["HUMAN"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["HUMAN-IND"]},
{"Q" : "Who was one of Napoleon's examiners while he was in school?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["HUMAN"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["HUMAN-IND"]},
{"Q" : "Where was Laplace born?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["LOCATION"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["LOCATION-CITY","LOCATION-STATE","LOCATION-COUNTRY"]},
{"Q" : "Where did Laplace go to school?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["LOCATION", "ENTITY"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["LOCATION-CITY","LOCATION-STATE","LOCATION-OTHER","ENTITY-OTHER"]},
{"Q" : "What did Laplace think of d'Alembert?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["DESCRIPTION","HUMAN"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["DESCRIPTION-REASON", "HUMAN-DESCRIPTION"]},
{"Q" : "What did d'Alembert think of Laplace?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["DESCRIPTION","HUMAN"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["DESCRIPTION-REASON", "HUMAN-DESCRIPTION"]},
{"Q" : "When did Laplace become a member of the Academie Des Sciences?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["NUMERIC"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["NUMERIC-DATE"]},
{"Q" : "Are Laplace's theories on celestial motion sufficient to describe the stability of the Solar System?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["DESCRIPTION"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["DESCRIPTION-REASON"]},
{"Q" : "How did Laplace's theory of ocean tides differ from that of Newton or Bernoulli?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["DESCRIPTION"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["DESCRIPTION-REASON","DESCRIPTION-DESCRIPTION"]},
{"Q" : "What sequence of functions, made by Legendre, did Laplace expand on?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["ENTITY"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["ENTITY-SYMBOL", "ENTITY-CREATIVE"]},
{"Q" : "What is a potential function?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["ENTITY","DESCRIPTION"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["ENTITY-SYMBOL","DESCRIPTION-DESCRIPTION"]},
{"Q" : "In what year did Laplace publish his book?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["NUMERIC"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["NUMERIC-DATE"]},
{"Q" : "What hypothesis was Laplace known for?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["DESCRIPTION","ENTITY"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["DESCRIPTION-DESCRIPTION","ENTITY-CREATIVE"]},
{"Q" : "What did Laplace do in statistics?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["DESCRIPTION", "ENTITY"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["DESCRIPTION-DESCRIPTION", "ENTITY-CREATIVE"]},
{"Q" : "Was Laplace involved in politics?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["DESCRIPTION", "HUMAN"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["DESCRIPTION-DESCRIPTION", "HUMAN-DESCRIPTION"]},
{"Q" : "What are Laplace's thoughts on governance?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["DESCRIPTION"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["DESCRIPTION-REASON", "DESCRIPTION-DESCRIPTION"]},
{"Q" : "Where did Laplace die?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["LOCATION"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["LOCATION-CITY", "LOCATION-COUNTRY", "LOCATION-STATE"]},
{"Q" : "What was Laplace's full name?", "Q_TYPE_COURSE" : ["HUMAN"], "Q_TYPE_FINE" : ["HUMAN-TITLE"]}
 ]
```

I AM ONLY USING THE LI AND ROTH "Q_TYPE_COURSE" tags. I have a feature extraction class where the features are extracted  and then turned into vector form using the following two methods (the feature_extractor.create_features method has spacy docs as inputs and returns a list of string features) (the vectorize features method takes the output of the create_features and turns its into a 1D coo_matrix that is later turned to a numpy array for prediction, where self is the qa_classifier class):

```
 feature_extractor.create_features(nlp(doc["Q"]), ngram_range=(1,3), lemmatize=True)

 self.vectorize_features(self, features)
```

now here is the qa_classifier class definition (assume the ngram ranges and lemmatize values are consistent throughout)

```
class qa_classifier(feature_extractor):

clfs = []
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
def _dummy_fun(s): return s
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer="word", tokenizer=_dummy_fun, preprocessor=_dummy_fun, token_pattern=None, norm="l2") 


def __init__(self, questions, tags, ngram_range=(2,2), lemmatize=False): 

    #train_questions is a list of lists of strings
    #assume that questions have already had the feature_extractor.create_features(question) method called on them
    #tags are strings
    self.ngram_range = ngram_range
    self.lemmatize = lemmatize

    self.q_matrix = qa_classifier.vectorizer.fit_transform(questions)

    self.tags_matrix = qa_classifier.mlb.fit_transform(tags)

    #here try to make a classifier for each tag
    for tag_idx in range(len(qa_classifier.mlb.classes_)):
        clf = svm.LinearSVC()
        clf.fit(self.q_matrix, self.tags_matrix.take(indices=tag_idx,axis=1))
        qa_classifier.clfs.append(clf)

def vectorize_features(self, features):
     #here we just use the q_matrix to turn new features into tf_idf docs
     #returns coo_matrix representing the feature vector

def predict(self,query):
    # query is a spacy doc
    query_features = feature_extractor.create_features(query) #turns a spacy doc into a list of strings
    feature_vector = self.vectorize_features(query_features).T.toarray()

    tags = []
    for tag_idx, clf in enumerate(qa_classifier.clfs):
        if clf.predict(feature_vector)[0] == 1:
            tags.append(qa_classifier.mlb.classes_[tag_idx])
    return tags
```

So basically I have various labels and use the multilabel binarizer to create binary classifiers for each tag and run each of the classifiers on a document in the predict method. However when I run the predict method on the training data shown above, it doesn't recreate the tags 100%, what is going on here?

Comment: Why exactly it *should*?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a linear classifier.

`clf = svm.LinearSVC()`

Your dataset is not linearly separable. This means if you were to plot out your datapoints on a graph you would not be able to draw a line between them that can completely put all the class labels with label X on one side and say label Y on other side. This is down to the datapoints themselves and this issue is ideally solved by some non linear classifer which can cover all the points by drawing a curve around them.

As an aside, 100% train accuracy is generally a very bad idea which means your model is overfitting and will not be able to generalize well to data it has not seen before.